# Why does the application still stop after setting the BackgroundService Exception Behavior.Ignore option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In asp.net core 6, I set an option so that when an exception occurs, the application does not stop
services.Configure(hostOptions =>
{
hostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior = BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore;
});

But it still stops, then starts itself. And nginx reverse proxy gives 502 error.
What can be done here so that the application simply logs an error, but does not restart?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just catch the exception in a try/catch and then run the task again.

In the following example, where the logic takes place, if there is an error this will be caught and then re-run every 60 seconds. This can obviously be adjusted to suit your requirements

```
public class YourWorker : BackgroundService
{

    private readonly ILogger<YourWorker> _logger;
    private readonly string _workerName;

    public YourWorker(Logger<YourWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _workerName = GetType().Name;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    //your logic here
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in worker: {workerName}", _workerName);
                }

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), stoppingToken);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Execution cancelled in worker: {workerName}", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception in worker: {workerName}, Excution stopping", _workerName);
        }
    }
}
```